Crash when inflating nested FragmentContainerView
Here is the structure of what I'm trying to achieve:
Activity -opens-> BottomSheetDialogFragment -inflates-> CustomView -inflates-> FragmentContainerView -inflates-> Fragment -inflates-> a few views

When running this I get the following crash (left out the details):
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.nestedfragments/com.example.nestedfragments.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.nestedfragments:layout/fragment_main_dialog: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.nestedfragments:layout/fragment_main_dialog: Error inflating class com.example.nestedfragments.ContainerView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.nestedfragments:layout/fragment_main_dialog: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.nestedfragments:layout/fragment_main_dialog: Error inflating class com.example.nestedfragments.ContainerView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.nestedfragments:layout/fragment_main_dialog: Error inflating class com.example.nestedfragments.ContainerView
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13 in com.example.nestedfragments:layout/view_container: Binary XML file line #13 in com.example.nestedfragments:layout/view_container: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13 in com.example.nestedfragments:layout/view_container: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions

MainActivity uses supportFragmentManager to open MainDialogFragment
MainDialogFragment
class MainDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        return FragmentMainDialogBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).root
    }
}

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.nestedfragments.ContainerView
        android:id="@+id/container_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

ContainerView
class ContainerView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val binding = ViewContainerBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this)
}

<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:parentTag="LinearLayout">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:name="com.example.nestedfragments.NestedFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</merge>

NestedFragment
class NestedFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        return FragmentNestedBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).root
    }
}

I'm using AndroidX Fragment 1.7.0-rc02
